# python convert image to array not working

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong here?
I have image that I like to convert to an array after some manipulation (rotation).
From some previous posts by others, my understanding is to call the numpy asarray command.  I tried it but the result is an object with 0 dimensions.  My original file is a .tif file (450 x 450 elements).  I also tried using the array command but gives me the same result.  My code is below.  Everything works except the last line.

```
im=Image.open("arbitrary_file.tif")
b=im.rotate(-30)
plt.imshow(b)
d=np.asarray(b)
```

Comment: It works fine for me.  Please post a link to the file in question and post your versions of numpy and PIL

Comment: if you have scipy you can try d = scipy.misc.imread('file.tif')

Comment: Thanks all.I finally got it to work.  There were some problems with importing PIL module.